# Slowness in Redis Client When using Azure Cache For Redis - redisinputstream.ensurefill

Tags: azure-redis-cache

We are using Azure Cache for Redis with 1 GB Standard Tier. Under higher load like 400 Concurrent in the application users Redis Write is becoming slow and also I am noticing slowness performance from same common method of redis client

```
 Class  redis.clients.jedis.util.RedisInputStream
Method  ensureFill
```

When cache is used it has 3 steps. Get the connection from pool, read/write and close connection. Above ensurefill is used on all 3 step which is strange.

Please see the call tree screeeshots below.

If you notice in all the steps of any cache retrieval, get resource from pool, get and close 3 methods endsup calling same redisinputstream.ensurefill, and all of time it is the most timeconsuming method.

My question is what is this method and why it has to be called all 3 times while once the connection is retrieve from the pool only should be simple read/write. Even for closing connection also it is calling ensurefill method.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is my pool config.

```
private static GenericObjectPoolConfig<Jedis> buildPoolConfig() {
    final JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
    poolConfig.setMaxTotal(200);
    poolConfig.setMaxIdle(100);
    poolConfig.setMinIdle(20);
    poolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    poolConfig.setTestOnReturn(true);
    poolConfig.setTestWhileIdle(true);
    poolConfig.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(Duration.ofSeconds(100).toMillis());
    poolConfig.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(Duration.ofSeconds(100).toMillis());
    poolConfig.setNumTestsPerEvictionRun(3);
    poolConfig.setBlockWhenExhausted(true);
    return poolConfig;
}
```

Comment: The `ensurefill` method is used to ensure that the input stream is filled with data before reading from it. It is called many times because it is used in all three steps of cache retrieval - get the connection from the pool, read/write, and close the connection. I am not sure, if this is the reason for slowness.